# select a column and filter values with select2 angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-select2

i am very new to angularjs. now i have a data table and a filter. in the filter, i have 2 select:column and value. pick a column and filter with the value. my idea is as following:

```
<tr ng-repeat="f in filters">
        <td>
          <select ng-model="f.column"
                  ui-select2
                  placeholder="Column"
                  class="form-control input-sm"
                  ng-change="filterChange()">
            <option ng-repeat="c in params.columns" value="{{c}}">{{elementMap[c].label}}</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        <select class="form-control input-sm"
                  ui-select2 
                  ng-model="f.value"
                  ng-change="filterChange()">
           <option ng-repeat="row in data.results" value="{{row.(f.column)}}">{{row.(f.column)}}</option>
        </select>
        </td>
</tr>
```

f.column is binded to the column name i pick up.
i need something like {{row.(f.column)}} which angularjs doesn't recognize.
is there any way to work around it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This directive is now obsolete. A new initiative, more active, and 100% angular is available at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select.